# Java Applet starts up very slowly for some users?

Tags: java, applet, performance, startup, freeze

[UPDATE: I forgot to add that this 30 sec. freezing problem only happens the first time I try to load a file from the server. Subsequent loads are very quick. Maybe some strange reverse DNS lookup? I am hosting on Google's appengine.]

I started a little project recently called http://www.chartle.net which is build around an applet.

Startup time is an important factor in the user's experience of an applet. I collect statistics and am shocked that I find often very long startup times (factor 50 to 100 higher then necessary)

The applet starts in 1-3 seconds depending on the speed of your computer and connection. Still for some users it takes up to 100 sec.

I have mixed results from my own tests. Mostly it is very fast but sometimes freezes the browser for a long time and the Java console doesn't tell me why. Best guess is, that it stalls when loading a saved chart.

Please help me figuring this out - best test by opening an already saved chart (click on one of the 'create' links at http://www.chartle.net/gallery)

Cheers,
Dieter

Answer (score 2):

This is generic help rather than specific for your demo (which loaded fine for me in a few attempts).

**Freezing applets**

In the JDK bin directory there is a very handy programme called [jstack](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jstack.html). Refresh your browser window until it crashes and then run:

```
jstack *process_id*
```

This will give you the stack trace of any frozen Java process. If Java is not a separate process then you can use the browser's process (eg for Opera).

The following few problems were/are common for me:

1. I reccommend you use invokeLater rather than invokeAndWait on the init method (although you can't do this if you use start/stop methods)
2. Opera's custom java plugin acts very poorly...
3. Deadlocks caused by synch blocks and invokeAndWait's

**Slow applets**

Possibly the browser is fetching resources from the server, unable to use the jar file?

Comment: Thanks but I already new those best practices. When I load a saved chart at startup it has to get that file from the server. Maybe delays here are caused bt some weird reverse DNS lookup. I have no clue so far.

Comment: Hmmm, have you thought a profiler? YourKit has a 15 day trial and plugs into applets quite easily. You should be able to see which line is causing the hang.

Answer (score 1):

It may be that only the old plugin causes these problems. That means basically all people running on OSX and other users with Java prior to 1.6_update_10.

So, I would really appreciate people with such setups to watch their Java console and describe the first startup behaviour.

Cheers,
Dieter